# Ruby + Rspec + OOP: Doubles/stubbing objects that the class uses, or instantiating actual class?

Tags: ruby, oop, rspec

I'm a rails developer and I'm trying to up my OOP game. Lately I've been watching talks by Sandi Metz and reading Design Patterns in Ruby.

There seems to be a fine line with when to use objects within objects (which causes dependencies?). I have a `Purchase` class that needs a `BankAccount` instance to withdraw money from. My test is failing because it I stubbed the `.balance` method for `bank_account` to return a fixed value. It seems like I'm stubbing quite a bit of stuff in this test, which seems like a warning to me. But a `Purchase` does require a stock and a bank account, so I am not sure if my design is too coupled or if this is inevitable:

```
    describe "#execute" do
        it 'withdraws money from the bank account' do
            stock = double('Stock')
            stock.stub(:price).and_return(1)
            bank_account = double('Bank Account')
            bank_account.stub(:balance).and_return(2000.00)
            bank_account.stub(:withdraw).and_return(bank_account.balance - (stock.price * 100))
            purchase = Purchase.new(stock, 100, bank_account)
            purchase.execute
            purchase.bank_account.balance.should eq(bank_account.balance - (stock.price * 100))
        end
    end
```

my purchase class:

```
class Purchase < Transaction
        attr_reader :shares

        def initialize(stock, shares, bank_account)
            super(stock, bank_account)
            @shares = shares
        end

        def execute #<-- trying to test this
            @bank_account.withdraw(@stock.price * @shares)
        end

    end
```

Is this more of a matter of my rspec test or my design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just writing a unit test, then all you want/need to do is ensure that the software under test makes the calls it needs to make to its collaborating objects. So, the following should suffice:

```
describe '#execute' do
  it 'withdraws money from the bank account' do
    stock_price = 1
    stock = double('stock', price: stock_price)
    shares = 100
    bank_account = double('bank_account')
    expect(bank_account).to receive(:withdraw).with(stock_price*shares)
    Purchase.new(stock, shares, bank_account).execute
  end
end
```

This test assumes that the initialize method of the `Transaction` super class stores `stock` and `bank_account` into instance variables.